# Google Colab isnt running faster than Jupyter Lab, Why and How does Google Colab function?

Tags: python, opencv, out-of-memory, google-colaboratory, large-data

I am very new to Google Colab, my data stored using joblib is about 18GiB. It can't run on Jupyter Lab as my PC has only 8GB of RAM, and will return `MemoryError`. I turned to Google Colab and just subscribed ColabPro to get the 25GB RAM and it finally loaded, but when I want to split the data, it exceeded 25GB.

The solution I could think of is to have the data already split in the joblib file. But when I use Google Colab to run previous preprocessing codes, it takes wayyyyy longer than doing it on localhost using Jupyter Lab.

It has been 2 hours and it is still stuck in one cell. Whereas Jupyter Labs took 30 minutes to run the whole notebook file.

I understand that the GPU and TPU option would be more useful in training complex Neural Network models, but I don't think it makes sense for my preprocessing notebook to run faster in my Jupyter Lab localhost compared to Google Colab.

The datasets I am working with are 87,000 images of ASL hand signs I got from Kaggle. The part where it takes a long time to run is resizing, converting, and normalizing those images into a NumPy array.

```
#  define new function to load images from source folder
def create_dataset_gray(img_folder):
    """
    read image file from the source folder and convert into the right color format, resize the image, convert image into a Numpy array with float as datatype 
    and Normalize image array to have values scaled down between 0 and 1.
    """
    # create empty list to store image arrays as X, and label for each image as y

X=[]
y=[]
    
    # iterate through the list of entries in the directory of specified folder
    for dir1 in os.listdir(img_folder):
        # print conversion progress of the code
        print("Converting and Importing images in file {} ...".format(dir1))
        # iterate through the images in the entries of the directory of specified folder
        for img in os.listdir(os.path.join(img_folder, dir1)):
            # set image path for each image
            image_path = os.path.join(img_folder, dir1, img)
            # utilise opencv package to read image from specified file
            image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert image into grayscale image
            # resize image read 
            image = cv2.resize(image, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA) # INTER_AREA is used when shrinking image is needed
            # set image value datatype as float
            image = image.astype("float")
            # divide 255 to normalize image array to have values between 0 and 1 
            image /= 255
            # append new image array and label into respective empty list 
            X.append(image)
            y.append(dir1)
    
    # set list as array for X and y
    X = np.asarray(X) 
    y = np.asarray(y)
    
    return X, y
```

This is the code it is taking forever to run.

Hope that someone can help you understand how Google Colab works:

1. Shouldn't it run faster compared to running it on my PC?
2. Is there a better solution to addressing the RAM issues?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the entire dataset into memory create a dataGenerator.
[https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)

With a little bit more code it will handle memory and multiprocessing for you

Comment: This would definitely be handy, I didn't come across this before, thanks! But I managed to get it running now, in the future I would definitely give this a go!